# Python - delete empty line from .txt, but last line don't delete

Tags: python, file

i have a test.txt file like this:

```
1 - test
2 - 
3 - test
4 -
```

(the numbers are just for example)

and my python code:

```
with open('test.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)
```

but the output.txt is:

```
1 - teste
2 - teste
3 -
```

I'd like to delete the last line too, but NOT with the code that erase the last line like this:

```
lines = file.readlines()
lines = lines[:-1]
```

How can i delete this last line checking with python if is a empty line?

Thanks!

Comment: It's usually a good idea to have a trailing newline at the end of a file. Are you sure you want to remove it?

Comment: yes, because the rest of my code doesn't works this way...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have an empty line at the end is because the last line ends with a newline. To remove the newline from the last line, you can read all the lines into a list, and then strip the last one:

```
with open('test.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # remove empty lines
    lines = [line for line in infile if line.strip()]

    # remove the newline from the last line
    if lines:
        lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip('\r\n')

    # write everything to disk
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution:

```
with open('test.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    lines = "\n".join([line.strip() for line in infile if line.strip()])
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```